# How to check a line of a file is present in the file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream, readline

I am new to javascript, I want to check whether the line of a file is there in the other file or not. I have the below code:

```
async getReadLiner(filename) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
    });
    return rl;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
checkLines() {
    const file1 = await this.getReadLiner(filename1);
    const file2 = await this.getReadLiner(filename2);
    for await (const line of file1) {
      for await (const file2Line of file2) { 
            if (file2Line == line) // It's not executing this line at all.
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Any idea why this line(if (`file2Line == line`) is not executing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `readLines.indexOf("helo 123") != -1`

Comment: @mplungjan - Only if you read the entire file as a big array. The `readline` module makes it possible to avoid that in favor of keeping with the streaming concept.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do something like

Yes, there's an [example of that](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line) in the documentation of the `readline` module, which looks like this:

> ```
> const fs = require('fs');
> const readline = require('readline');
>
> async function processLineByLine() {
>   const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
>
>   const rl = readline.createInterface({
>     input: fileStream,
>     crlfDelay: Infinity
>   });
>   // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
>   // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.
>
>   for await (const line of rl) {
>     // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
>     console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
>   }
> }
>
> processLineByLine();
> ```

Adapting the loop in that:

```
const targetLine = "helo 123";
for await (const line of getReadLiner(/*...*/)) {
    if (line === targetLine) { // Or line.includes(targetLine) for a substring match
        // Found it
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if the targetLine is coming from another file, it's not waiting.  Something like this https://pastebin.com/iZ9iptWQ

Comment: @lakshmiravalirimmalapudi - I don't know what you mean by that. The question shows `line` being a constant (I've renamed it `targetLine` in the code above, because `line` is a good name for the `for-await-of` control variable). What's "not waiting"? (`for-await-of` definitely waits for the stream to produce a line.) There's nothing in the question about getting the line you're looking for from another file.

Comment: Edited the question. Looking for something like this https://pastebin.com/iZ9iptWQ